# how to create readonly user for webdav connection to marklogic

Tags: marklogic, webdav, windows-explorer, marklogic-9

I'm using marklogic 9.0-8 on windows 10. In marklogic, I need to setup webdav so operator can see all the documents. But I only want to give webdav readonly permission, this is to avoid accidents.

step1: I created a role called "readonly", (not compartment), give this role the following permission:

```
a. execute privileges: any-uri, rest-reader, role-exists, role-get-description, role-get-external-names
b. uri-previleges:  view-uri
c. role name (capability):   readonly (read)
```

step 2: I then created a user called "test-user", assign role "readonly" to this user

step 3: using DMSDK async, I load documents into marklogic, with metadata permission : role "readonly".
here I didn't specify the capability for role at loading data time, so I assume it takes the default permission assigned to role "readonly"

step 4: now I setup webdav app server called webdav-appserver. 
for this server, the default user is "test-user"; root is "/". database points to my db, port 10001. others are default.

step5. now on windows, I create webdav to connection to database, using "http:localhost:10001".
it will ask for userid and password.
when I provide user "test-user" and password, it will complains "windows cannot access http://localhost:10001/".
but if I connect using "admin" user, then I can connect.

question 1:
I expect that I can use user "test-user" for webdav to connect to marklogic, and once connected, on windows, even operator can see the documents, the documents are readonly, oeprators cannot modify or delete. but the problem is  I cannot connect using "test-user".

question 2 regarding this: if I connect the webdav using admin user, the webdav can connect, I can see documents from windows system. but when I open the pdf file from webdav, it will ask me for userid/password.  after I provide "test-user" and password, then I can see pdf files. it will ask userid and password everytime.  But for xml files it doesn't ask userid/password.

My expectation is: once I connected to marklogic using webdav with my "test-user", I should be able to see pdf files, I should not be asked to provide userid/password each time.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks, Helen

Comment: https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/252/0/read-only-access-user-for-webdav

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try it.

Comment: Following the link I created readonly account for webdav. seems working. One thing is I have pdf files. when I want to view pdf files through webdav, it always ask for uid/pwd everytime, even I clicked "save credentials". is there any configuration  that can remove this uid/pwd popup?    another strange thing is: through webdav on windows, I can't create folder/file, but I can select a file and delete it. it will be gone from explorer,  but actually still in marklogic. when I refresh the explorer, the file shows again. good thing it is not deletion, but still weird. Any configuration for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a Windows Explorer WebDAV problem, not a MarkLogic problem. Test on another WebDAV client.

And in Windows Explorer, when connecting to the root of a WebDAV server, you have to replace the root `/` with `/DavWWWRoot/`. This may or may not be related to your issue.

Finally, read [the documentation on URI privileges](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/uri-privilege). If you intend to create a read-only user, then do not give them any URI privileges, which permits **creating** documents at the URI path specified by the privilege.

Comment: I have 2 marklogic user, one is super user "admin", another is I created user "test-user". if it is windows explorer webdav problem, then both users should have problems. But for me, the admin user works, the test-user does not work.

Comment: @Helen Did you try connecting to the Windows Explorer-specified root directory?

Comment: I just created webdav server on marklogic, the root directory is "/", same as other servers.  I have 2 marklogic users. and then I tried to connect from windows explorer to marklogic webdav server using "Map network drive"